# Webpack can't find npm link'd module

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm working on two Node.js packages. One is a Vue.js component and the other is a project that will use it. I'll call them `library` and `consumer` respectively.

This is what I've done so far:

1. `cd library && npm link && cd ..` (link library globally)
2. `cd consumer && npm link library` (register it with consumer)

Now when I try to run webpack-dev-server in `consumer` I get an error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'library' in 'C:\Projects\consumer\src'
```

When I look in the consumer's `node_modules` I see a symlink to the library, but for some reason webpack isn't resolving it. Based on the error message, it seems like it's not falling back to `node_modules` to look for it.

I've been looking over this [widely-cited help doc](https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#npm-linked-modules-doesn-t-find-their-dependencies) about webpack + `npm link`, which recommends adding `path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')` to `resolve.modules`, but I'm still getting the same error.

This is on Windows but I've tried the same process on a Linux machine with the same result.

Has anyone been successful in getting webpack to work with `npm link`?